# How can I stop PlotRangePadding from cutting off points in a ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

When I perform a 2D plot and want to highlight specific spots in the plane, ListPlot seems like a good idea. However once I want to get rid of the padding, my points are getting cut off. This is specifically bad if I want to emphasize different spots with different symbols. A (somewhat)minimal example that shows the issue is

```
Show[{
  ContourPlot[1/(1 + x^2 + y^2), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> None], 
  ListPlot[Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 1, .5}, {j, 0, 1, .5}], 
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[.1]]
}]
```

Which produces

[image: The points are cut off!]

How can I create a plot without padding where the Points will not get cut off?

Comment: `,
PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 20, ImageMargins -> 0`

Comment: @Kuba PlotRangeClipping is the culprit. Thank you!

Comment: argh that should have been `PlotRangeClipping->False, PlotRange->All`